# Why formData does not take the data there is in the state and that has been refreshed, there is a delay character ? React

Tags: reactjs, use-state, form-data

when i write in an input , i update the state (hook useState) and the state i put it in formData and the key ficheUser. With each keystroke the function where the setData and formData is located is executed.

But I notice that there is still a letter behind, there is a letter missing in formData compared to the state see the screenshot.

And I dont understand why ?

```
const changeHandler = (event) => {
    const enteredNom = nomInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredPrenom = prenomInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredAge = ageInputRef.current.value;
    
    console.log("------->event.target");
    // console.log(event.target.files)
    // console.log(event.target.files[0])

    let newPhoto;
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length === 1) {
      newPhoto = event.target.files[0];
    }

    console.log("-->newPhoto");
    console.log(newPhoto);

    //Update the state
    setDataUpdate(prevState => ({
      ...prevState.dataUpdate,
      nom: enteredNom,
      prenom: enteredPrenom,
      age: enteredAge,
      // newPhoto: newPhoto,
    }));

    //send new data to backend
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", newPhoto);
    formData.append("ficheUser", JSON.stringify(dataUpdate));

    console.log("----->formData");
    console.log(formData.get("image"));
    console.log(formData.get("ficheUser"));
    console.log("---------------");

    const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/fiche_user/71?userId=92";
    const fetchUploadHandler = async () => {
```

[image]

Comment: It's because setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync.

Comment: Any idea for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I am in self-training on React.js, I took the day to find the solution and it is very simple.

just take the values of the refs and put them in an object and especially not in useState and then put this object in formData... and it works there is no more delay letter

```
const changeHandler = (event) => {
const enteredNom = nomInputRef.current.value;
const enteredPrenom = prenomInputRef.current.value;
const enteredAge = ageInputRef.current.value;

//création de l'objet avec propriétés à envoyer dans formData
const dataUpdateFormData = {
  nom: enteredNom,
  prenom: enteredPrenom,
  age: enteredAge,
};

console.log("--->dataUpdateFormData");
console.log(dataUpdateFormData);

//envoyer les nouvelles données vers le serveur
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", newPhoto);
formData.append("ficheUser", JSON.stringify(dataUpdateFormData));

console.log("----->formData");
console.log(formData.get("image"));
console.log(formData.get("ficheUser"));
console.log("---------------");

const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/fiche_user/71?userId=92";
const fetchUploadHandler = async () => {
```